# using namespace

Tags: namespaces, c++-cli

what is the difference between

```
using System;
```

and

```
using namespace System;
```

is it the same thing?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference.  The first one doesn't compile.  Maybe you meant this:

```
#using <System.dll>
using namespace System;
```

The #using directive allows you to reference an assembly without going through the Framework and References project setting.