# Difference between 'using' and 'using namespace'

Tags: c++, namespaces

In the boost libraries, there are often examples of including the library like:

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
```

Throughout my program I have been importing namespaces like this:

```
#include "../MyClass.h"
using namespace MyClassNamespace;
```

Can someone please explain:

1. The difference between `using` and `using namespace`;
2. What the advantage of negating the use of `using namespace` in favour of `using`;
3. The differences in forward declaring `using` and `using namespace`;

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [using namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906540/using-namespace)

Comment: @user657267 not really.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Well sort of IMO, the linked answer tries to point out that the two statements have completely different use cases, you can't say `using somenamespace` any more than you can say `using namespace notanamespace`.

Comment: @user657267 I saw the linked answer before I published this question, but I didn't think it answered my questions adequately enough

Comment: The correct terms are "using declaration" and "using directive". http://stackoverflow.com/q/16152750/981959 has some relevant answers

Comment: @redFIVE: This question is now the first result on Google.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`using namespace`    makes visible all the names of the namespace, instead stating `using` on a specific object of the namespace makes only that object visible.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iostream>

void print(){
using std::cout; 
using std::endl;
cout<<"test1"<<endl;
}
int main(){
 using namespace std;
cout<<"hello"<<endl;
print();
return 0;
}
```

- while using "using namespace std" all the elements under the scope of std are made available under scope of the function.
- while using "using std::cout" we explicitly mention what element under the std is required for the function ,without importing all the elements under std.

> this is my first answer in stack overflow please correct me if iam wrong!!